# Express $x=0.\overline{31}_5$ as a fraction in lowest terms

Tags: fractions

> Given $x=0.\overline{31}_5$, find the value of $x$, expressed as a fraction in lowest terms.

I tried to change it into base $10$, but I don't think it's possible with fractions. So please help I'll appreciate it. Also I'm in 7th grade (easy solutions please) and no copying other people's answer (I've seen it in other problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x=.\overline{31}_5$$
$$100_5x=31.\overline{31}_5$$
subtracting the top from the bottom we get 
$44_5x=31_5$ (comment if you dont understand why $100_5-1_5=44_5$)

Solving for $x$ we get $x=\frac{31}{44}$ as a base $5$ fraction. To simplify, we convert to base 10 
$$x=\frac{16}{24}=\frac{2}{3}$$

This works like converting base-10 recurring fractions (practice -- it's a good tool to have).

Comment: what do you mean it works like base-10?

Comment: This method is usually applied to base-10 fractions, but in this answer the OP has applied it to base-5.

Comment: @RossMillikan $100_5x$ not just 100

Comment: This is not correct.  $100_5x$ is $31.\overline 1_5,$ not $31.3\overline 1_5$.  My earlier comment was also incorrect.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes you are right i meant to put that. sorry

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to converting repeating decimals to fractions works here.  Multiply it by $5$.  Then subtract $5x-x$ and the repeating part disappears.  You are left with $4x=$ something.  Now convert that something to base $10$ because you are probably expected to give a result in base $10$.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated solution:**

$0.31_5 = \frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{25} = \frac{16}{25}$.

$0.\overline{31}_5 = 0.31_5 + 0.0031_5 + 0.000031_5 + \cdots$. Now using the formula for an infinite geometric series:

$$0.\overline{31}_5 = \frac{0.31_5}{1 - 0.01_5} = \frac{16/25}{1-1/25} = \frac{16}{24} = \frac{2}{3}.$$

---

Old solution:

$x = 0.3_5 + 0.0\overline1_5$.

Now $0.\overline 4_5 = 1$. $0.0\overline1 \cdot 10_5 \cdot 4_5 = 1$, so $0.0\overline1 = \frac{1}{5 \cdot 4} = \frac{1}{20}$

Using the fact that $0.3_5 = \frac{3}{5}$, $x = \frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{20} = \frac{13}{20}$.

Note:
$0.\overline 4_5 = 1$ is the equivalent of $0.\overline{99} =1$. To prove this you can break it into $0.4_5 + 0.04_5 + 0.004_5 + \cdots$, which is an infinite geometric series and evaluates to $\frac{0.4_5}{1 - 0.1_5} = \frac{4/5}{1 - 1/5} = 1$.

Comment: thanks but that's a little too complex for me

Comment: Unfortunate note... OP edited $x=0.3\overline{1}_5$ to $x=0.\overline{31}_5$.

Comment: sry but I still appreciate your answer :)

Comment: I tried to write an alternative solution given that the more 'normal' solution was already written. Don't worry: I wouldn't expect a 7th grader to accept $0.999 \cdots = 1$, much less accept the same fact in base $5$.

Comment: thanks for the new solution, it makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the geometric series formula; that is, for $|a|<1$ you have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n= \frac a{1-a}.$$

Now,
$$.\overline{31}_5=3\cdot 5^{-1}+1\cdot 5^{-2}+3\cdot 5^{-3}+1\cdot 5^{-4}+\cdots=$$
$$=3\cdot 5\cdot 5^{-2}+1\cdot 5^{-2}+3\cdot 5\cdot 5^{-4}+1\cdot 5^{-4}+\cdots=$$
$$=16\cdot 5^{-2}+16\cdot 5^{-4}+\cdots=16\left(\frac1{25}+\left(\frac1{25}\right)^2+\cdots\right)=$$
$$=16\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{25}\right)^n= 16\cdot\frac {\frac1{25}}{1-\frac1{25}}=\frac23.$$

Comment: Wow a lot like toby mak's solution but none of the less a good one, Thx :)